# vba find file path using increment?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use the following vba code to find the file path of my file:

Lets say i have a file called text.xlsx

This could be stored in

```
G:\Folder\1. 2017

    Or 

    G:\Folder\2. 2017

    Or

    G:\Folder\3. 2017

    etc
```

So i am trying to use a for loop that will check numbers 1 to 10

To ensure the path is found.

```
Sub PlannerOpen()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10
Path = "G:\Folder\" & i & ". " & Year(Date) & "\"
MsgBox Path & "*.xlsx"
i = i + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

This only seems to produce numbers 1, 3, 5 and 9.

Am i doing something wrong?
Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `For i = 1 to 10` line is the start of a *loop*, setting `i` to `1` and will increment it by `1` on each iteration (unless otherwise specified with `Step`) until it reaches `10`.

Your loop starts on `1`, creates the `Msgbox` with `1` but you then manually increase `i` to `2` with the line `i = i + 1`. Then it returns to the start of the loop and by default increment `i` again by `1` as per design, setting it to `3`.

Remove your manual `i = i + 1` incrementation and allow the loop to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove below line as it is not necessary

```
i = i + 1
```